# How to manually hide a popover with Bootstap 5?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, popover, bootstrap-popover

I am trying to create multiple Bootstrap popover instances with the ability to close all when on click.

Here is what I did

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    var items = [];

    document.getElementById('addPopperButton', function () {
        var btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        btn.innerText = 'Toggle poppver';

        var item = new bootstrap.Popover(btn, {
            trigger: 'hover click',
            title: 'lorem text',
            content: 'lorem text'
        });

        items.push(item);

        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    });

    document.getElementById('hideAllPopovers', function () {
        items.forEach(item => {
            item.popover('hide');
        });
    });

});
```

However this keeps giving me the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: item.popover is not a function

How can I manually hide all the popover instances when the `hideAllPopovers` is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Bootstrap 5**, you can hide a popover using `hide` method:

```js
const popoverInstance = new bootstrap.Popover(triggerElement, options);

// manually hide
popoverInstance.hide()
```

`$().popover('hide')` was used in Bootstrap v3 & 4.

In your code, `item` is a popover instance, so you should  replace `item.popover('hide');` with `item.hide();`.

```js
document.getElementById('hideAllPopovers').addEventListener('click', () => {
  items.forEach((item) => {
    item.hide();
  });
});
```

**Stackblitz demo**:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-chdxor?file=src%2Findex.js

---

From **[Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/popovers/#methods)**, `hide` method:

> Hides an element’s popover. Returns to the caller before the popover has actually been hidden (i.e. before the hidden.bs.popover event occurs). This is considered a “manual” triggering of the popover.

Comment: Worked! strange the bootstrap documents show `.popover('hide')` not `.hide()`

Comment: In Bootstrap 5, `$elemTrigger.popover(hide)` would have worked if you were using jquery; see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/javascript/#optionally-using-jquery.